# R: Remove dots in text but not those marking decimal points

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am a new comer to regular expressions, so please bear with me.

I have a string like this:

```
txt1 <- 'a,b,a.b,a.,1,2,1.2,1.,.,11,222,11.222,11.'
```

Imagine it is from a .csv and each cell is separated by ','. Now I would like to remove all '.' except those marking decimal points. In this end, I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
txt2 <- 'a,b,ab,a,1,2,1.2,1,,11,222,11.222,11'
```

I have tried the following codes:

```
txt2 <- gsub(pattern = '[^a-z0-9,(\\d\\.\\d)]', replacement = '', text = txt1)
txt2 <- gsub(pattern = '[^a-z0-9,|(\\d\\.\\d)]', replacement = '', text = txt1)
```

But neither works, both returning

```
> print(txt2)
[1] "a,b,a.b,a.,1,2,1.2,1.,.,11,222,11.222,11."
```

Any idea how I might correct my codes? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use the negative lookbehind `?<!` and negative lookahead `?!`

```
> txt1 <- 'a,b,a.b,a.,1,2,1.2,1.,.,11,222,11.222,11.'
> txt2 <- gsub(pattern='((?<![0-9])\\.)|(\\.(?![0-9]))', replacement='', x=txt1, perl=TRUE)
> txt2
[1] "a,b,ab,a,1,2,1.2,1,,11,222,11.222,11"
```

This pattern  matchs a period `\\.` that is proceeded by a character that is not `0-9` or a period that is followed by a character that is not `0-9`. You have to set `perl=TRUE` for R to recognize the lookbehind and lookahead.

This will trim leading period characters, so '.2' will become '2'. If this is not wanted, the lookbehind needs to be `(?<![0-9,])`.

Comment: What is the purpose of putting `\.` inside a capturing group here?

Comment: There is no need for a lookbehind, see above two answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It is very helpful!

Comment: @CAustin I edited out the capturing group- turns out you don't need it. @MauritsEvers The lookbehind is there to exclude values like 'A.2' and '.2' (it looked like the OP wanted to trim the period characters). If OP wants to keep leading period characters, like in '.2', the lookbehind should be `(?<![0-9,])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead. Match `\.(?!\d)` and replace it with nothing.

https://regex101.com/r/LNHYOY/1

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The link is extremely useful!

Comment: Here is a follow up question that I hope you'd kindly answer as well. Since brackets `()` are not recognized in a list `[]`, how do I code to recognize something that is not in a group? Is `(?!(the group))` the only way?

Comment: Are you talking about a way to negate an entire string, similar to how `[^abc]` negates the individual characters a, b, and c? There's no way to exactly reproduce the way that works, but negative lookahead (using `(?! ... )` like in the answer above) can be used to achieve something close.

Comment: I see. Thank you again for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookahead (as suggested by @CAustin) seems to be the most elegant and concise.

Since none of the above solutions give you the actual R code, here it is:

```
txt2 <- gsub("\\.(?!\\d)", "", txt1, perl = TRUE)
[1] "a,b,ab,a,1,2,1.2,1,,11,222,11.222,11"
```